# Evaluate the integral along the stated curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

$\int_{C}{(3x+2y) \, dx + (2x-y) \, dy}$
along the curve y = sin($\pi*x\over2$) from (0,0) to (1,1). (Given that the curve is smooth).

**Approach:**
I attempted this problem by parametrizing x = $\pi*t\over2$ and y = sin(t), but that wasn't working out since I got this:
∫3t + 2sin($\pi*t\over2$) + ($\pi$)*t*cos($\pi*t\over2$) - ($\pi\over2$)*cos($\pi*t\over2$)*sin($\pi*t\over2$).
I then attempted x = t and y = sin($\pi*t\over2$), which didn't help.

I'm having trouble finding which parametrization works (the integration should follow easy from there). Can some help out with the setup of the parameters?

Thanks

Comment: why is your first attempt difficult?

Comment: I think I messed up the parameters.

Comment: It would be what Adriano suggested:
\begin{align*}
x = \frac{2}{\pi}t &\implies dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\, dt \\
y = \sin t &\implies dy = \cos t \, dt \\
\end{align*}
I just didn't look carefully enough at the x to manipulate it to t in order to have y = sin(t).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have made a typo with your first attempt. If we want $y = \sin t$, then we need to ensure that $t = \frac{\pi}{2}x$, so we have:
\begin{align*}
x = \frac{2}{\pi}t &\implies dx = \frac{2}{\pi}\, dt \\
y = \sin t &\implies dy = \cos t \, dt \\
\end{align*}
So our line integral becomes:
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2} (3 \cdot \tfrac{2}{\pi}t + 2 \cdot \sin t) \cdot \tfrac{2}{\pi}\, dt
+ \int_0^{\pi/2} (2 \cdot \tfrac{2}{\pi}t - \sin t) \cdot \cos t \, dt
$$
which is not too bad to evaluate.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_{C}{(3x+2y) \, dx + (2x-y) \, dy} = \int_{C}{3x \, dx - y \, dy + 2 \,d(xy)}
=\left[\frac32 x^2 - \frac12 y^2 + 2xy \right]_{0,0}^{1,1} \\
= 3
$$